# How to deal with ContraintViolationException and other Exceptions

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, apache-camel

I have a camel route like this:

```
this.from(uri).process(e -> {

    String json = e.getIn().getBody(String.class);

    JsonObject message = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
    Status status = gson.fromJson(message.get("data"), Status.class);

    e.getIn().setHeader("JSON_OBJECT", message);
    e.getIn().setBody(status);
}).to(jpaStatusUri).process(e -> {
    JsonObject message = (JsonObject) e.getIn().getHeader("JSON_OBJECT");
    StatusDetails details = gson.fromJson(message.get("data"), StatusDetails.class);
    // If the first route was successfull i can get the id of the inserted entity here (this works)
    details.setStatusId(e.getIn().getBody(Status.class).getId());
    e.getIn().setBody(details);
}).to(jpaDetailsUri);
```

I send the entity `Status` to a jpa endpoint `jpaStatusUri`. The entity is inserted, and in the following `process()` method i create a corresponding `StatusDetails` entity, set it's statusId to the id of the previously saved `Status` and send it to the `jpaDetailsUri` endpoint.

This works as expected in case the `Status` entity has been saved successfully. In case of a `ConstraintViolationException` i.e. a unique key for the `Status` entity already exists this will throw the exception, i will not have a correct `statusId` and i will not be able to update the corresponding `StatusDetails` entity anymore.

Of course i could all handle this in the process() method, but what would be the "camel-way" to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A camel-way to handle such things would be to use an `onException` :

```
 onException(ConstraintViolationException.class)
     .process(e -> {e.getIn().setBody(new ErrorObjectJson());})
     .handled(true)
```

check out the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html)

There is also the [try-catch](http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html) way of handling exception that is provided by camel.

Comment: My question was a bit more about "how to get the key of the violating entity". But with the onException i can at least react on the problem. With continued(true) instead of handled(true) i can search for and set the id myself.